# About the diagonalization of non-linear (in fields) actions

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, interactions, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems

Suppose we have some interacting theory with the action:
$$
S = \int d^{D} x \left(\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi  + V(\phi)\right)
$$
Where $V(\phi)$ is a potential (some polynomial of degree $>2$, $\cosh$, whatever makes the equation of motion nonlinear). If one knew in principle a general solution of equation of motion, corresponding to the action above:
$$
\phi(\alpha)
$$
where $\alpha$ is some set of parameters determining the solution, which for the case of quadratic action is the momentum $k$, would one obtain the quadratic action in the diagonal form:
$$
S = \int d \alpha \ \phi(\alpha) M(\alpha) \phi(\alpha)
$$
Where $M(\alpha)$ is some diagonal matrix, depending on these parameters $\alpha$, or this action would be diagonalized in some other sense?

I am not aware of the interacting theories, where the general solution does exist (probably for my shame), for the case of $\phi^4$ theory in $4D$ there is a *Fubini instanton* https://inspirehep.net/literature/108217, kinks in $2D$ field theory with double well potential, *Sine-gordon* model, instantons in the Yang-Mills theories, but these are rather special solutions.

Are there any examples of theories, where the generic solution is known?

Or the presence of such a potential would imply, that this theory is unsolvable in principle? And one can obtain a solution only in form of perturbation series?

I would be grateful for comments and suggestions!

Comment: Try the Sinh-Gorgon equation. I believe the general solution is known. Similarly, Cosh-Gorgon, Sin-Gordon.

Comment: Are you looking for classical or quantum systems?

Comment: @Cream I would be interested to know at least on a classical level. At quantum, as far as I understand, there will be an additional complication from the Jacobian in the measure after the field redefinition